# SQL Ordering a complex query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have these tables:

`items`, which stores items.

```
CREATE TABLE items
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name character varying(255),
  rarity character varying(255),
  created_at timestamp without time zone,
  updated_at timestamp without time zone,
  CONSTRAINT items_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

`item_modifiers`, which manages the many-to-many relationship between items and modifiers

```
CREATE TABLE item_modifiers
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  item_id integer,
  modifier_id integer,
  primary_value integer,
  secondary_value integer,
  CONSTRAINT item_modifiers_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

`modifiers` , which contains all possible item modifiers

```
CREATE TABLE modifiers
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT explicit_mods_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Now suppose I have a complex query. I want to find all items that have modifiers with ID 1 and 2, ordered by the primary_value of the modifier with ID 1.

I have tried this query

```
SELECT "items".*, item_modifiers.primary_value FROM "items" 
INNER JOIN item_modifiers ON item_modifiers.item_id = items.id
AND ((item_modifiers.modifier_id = 1) 
OR (item_modifiers.modifier_id = 2)) 
GROUP BY items.id, item_modifiers.primary_value
HAVING 
COUNT(item_modifiers.id) = 2 
ORDER BY item_modifiers.primary_value DESC
```

But it returns an empty result set. However when I don't group by the primary_value, it does, but then I can't order it. I've been stuck on this for ages, so any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT** I have built an SQL fiddle to demonstrate
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/30887/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to join with item_modifiers with the modifier_id 2, you only want it guaranteed that such a records EXISTS:

```
SELECT items.*, item_modifiers.primary_value 
FROM items 
INNER JOIN item_modifiers ON item_modifiers.item_id = items.id AND item_modifiers.modifier_id = 1
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM item_modifiers 
  WHERE item_modifiers.item_id = items.id AND item_modifiers.modifier_id = 2
)
ORDER BY item_modifiers.primary_value DESC;
```

Here is your SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/30887/9

Comment: Here is another way of solving this with only a slight change to your statement: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/30887/17.

Comment: This is almost it, except now (on my production db) some primary_values are blank and they are appearing at the top. Is there any way for the blank values to appear at the bottom using the CASE THEN WHEN part in your second sqlfiddle?

Comment: As the primary_value is an integer, a blank value means NULL. You can use ORDER BY .... DESC NULLS LAST to move them to the end of your result list.

Comment: Wow, amazing, wasn't even aware of this syntax (coming from mysql background)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for :

```
SELECT "items".*, 
       item_modifiers.primary_value 
FROM   "items" 
       INNER JOIN item_modifiers 
               ON item_modifiers.item_id = items.id 
                  AND ( ( item_modifiers.modifier_id = 1 ) 
                         OR ( item_modifiers.modifier_id = 2 ) ) 
ORDER  BY item_modifiers.primary_value DESC;
```